# Oil for old 4.5V motor? (UK)

Tags: technic, motor, repair

I've just got my old LEGO Technic motor from my loft. It works but squeals in a way I don't remember it doing (35 years ago). I assume some lubrication would help and I've seen references to [3-IN-ONE SAE 20](https://3inone.com/product/3-in-one-motor-oil/) but that only seems to be available in the USA. Any suggestions for the UK?

Comment: Start with a food grade mineral oil something like this: [picture](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/713UV0K5ccL._AC_SL1500_.jpg)

Comment: Would standard 3 in one (which I already have) do the job or is that too thick? A full bottle of the food grade stuff at £8 seems excessive when I only need a drop!

Comment: Hi Derek, is this your motor? ([bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6216m2#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D))

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: @Derek Composition of 3-in-1 oil products can vary a lot. Some are safe (like the SAE20), others will eat the ABS plastic LEGO is made of. Without details on the exact brand/type of oil you have at home, we can;t advise if it is safe or not.

Comment: Ah apologies. This is the bottle I have https://www.amazon.co.uk/One-Oil-100ml-Drip-Can/dp/B00SJQEMPG/ref=sr_1_30?dchild=1&keywords=3+in+one&qid=1603291869&sr=8-30